# Why two two users with same username and different hostnames are considered different accounts?

Tags: mariadb

As I understand in mariadb two users with same username and different hostnames are considered two different accounts?

```
create user employee@192.168.1.2;
create user employee@192.168.1.3;
```

Does it create two different accounts?
And what is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are two different accounts.

Each host will have its own users... Similarly, the root or administrator password on host1 is usually not the same as the root or administrator password on host2.
Think of the *@192.168.1.2* as the family name, and *employee* as the given name. Just because family1 has a child named Bulat, and family2 also has a child named Bulat, the two Bulats are not the same person.